# Can you create a new JVM in a c++ function called from java using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, c, dll, jvm

So my setup is that I have a .dll which is developed by me (**A.dll**) which in the original application is called from an external process which is basically just a .exe file that I do not have the source code for (**B.exe**). The purpose of **A.dll** is to communicate with a .jar file, which is also developed by me (**C.jar**). So in the application, the "communication flows" as shown below

**B.exe** -> **A.dll** -> *(through JNI)* -> **C.jar**

Now, what i want to do is to add the calls going between **A.dll** and **C.jar**  as a part of my test suite in the development environment for **C.jar**. What I have so far is that I have created another .dll (**D.dll**) which mirrors all functions in **A.dll**, but with JNIEXPORT, and simply makes direct call to the respective function in **A.dll**. So the "communication flow" in this situation will be as follows:

*Unit test in C.jar development framework* -> (through JNI) -> **D.dll** -> **A.dll** -> (through JNI) -> **C.jar**

At this point, a very simple function call that simply prints out something in **C.jar** works through the whole chain; all the way from the unit test call and into **C.jar**. The problem however arises when i call the function in **A.dll** which creates a new JVM using **CreateJavaVM()**, which produces the following error:

***Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: The specified procedure could not be found***

So basically I'm wondering if it is actually possible to do this, or is it just simply impossible to call *CreateJavaVM()* when there is already a running JVM in the same process? I know that you can't call *CreateJavaVM()* several times within the same process, but in this situation it is only called once but a JVM already exists in the process - can you even have several JVMs running in the same process?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @apangin's answer the code snippet below solved my problem:

```
jsize nVMs = 0; 
JavaVM** buffer;

jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs = (GetCreatedJavaVMs) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(
  TEXT("jvm.dll")), "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");

if (jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs == NULL) {
  // stuff
  CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, &args);
} else {
  jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs(NULL, 0, &nVMs); // 1. just get the required array   length
  JavaVM** buffer = new JavaVM*[nVMs];
  jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs(buffer, nVMs, &nVMs); // 2. get the data
  buffer[0]->GetEnv((void **) &env, jni_version); // 3. get environment
  jvm = buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: nice question, but I would keep each tier responsibility as it is instead of tight coupling. C.jar doesnt need to know anything about client, architectural changes can be painful for fixes. I would keep unit tests of C.jar just for its own methods, then A.dll tests would run through itself and JNI results as well. Then put into some continous integration server. Are you able to test c.jar results via a.dll?

Comment: But the coupling between A.dll and C.jar is already very tight because of the JNI interface. I already have a separate test suite for A.dll that calls into C.jar, but i just feel like it would be nicer if I could have all the tests in one place, since the coupling between A.dll and C.jar is so tight anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current JNI specification explicitly states that *[creation of multiple VMs in a single process is not supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_CreateJavaVM)*, and this is actually asserted in [HotSpot source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c9035b8e388b/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l5163).

Even if your dll calls `JNI_CreateJavaVM` only once, it does not mean that this is the very first call within the whole process. In fact, `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is first called by `java.exe` or by another launcher of your IDE (`idea.exe`, `eclipse.exe`, `netbeans.exe` etc).

Therefore, instead of creating Java VM blindly, `A.dll` should check first if JVM already exists in current process by calling [JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs). If the function returns nonempty array, then use [GetEnv](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#GetEnv) or [AttachCurrentThread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) to obtain `JNIEnv*` for the existing VM, otherwise create a new VM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, currently testing things out

Comment: It seems like the JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs terminates the whole process if no VMs exists... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out - silly mistake really.

So i get the JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs function like this:

`jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs = (GetCreatedJavaVMs) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(
    TEXT("jvm.dll")), "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");`

and i forgot to check if `jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs` was NULL before calling 

`jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs(NULL, 0, &nVMs);`

Comment: As the C++ code is stated to be called from Java, it is impossible for `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs()` to return no JVMs. Difficult to see what thiis question or the alleged solution is about,

Comment: @EJP Please, read the question carefully before downvoting. It clearly states that `A.dll` can be called either from an external (non-Java) application `B.exe` **or** from a Java framework `C.jar`.